# Creating reference library for Python scripts?

Tags: arcpy

We run a few scripts at my office in Python that automate some of our map making processes, but we're trying to consolidate everything as much as possible, in doing so we wanted to create a reference library that a script can be directed to for a specific variable.

For instance, one of our scripts pulls latitudes and longitudes from a CSV and maps them, however, the headings often change and can be anything from "Latitude" to "EST - LAT - SITE" depending on the type of report used.

Currently we're defining these in each individual script as:

LAT = ['Lat', 'lat', 'LAT', 'Latitude', 'latitude', 'LATITUDE'] (I've left some out because it's sensitive data)

Is there any way to define all of our variable that are frequently used (roughly 60) and point the script towards the file containing the definitions as opposed to writing them out every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I use is to look at all of the fields in the table of the required type, then use a SearchCursor to scan the table and eliminate those attributes in which **any entry** does not match whatever qualifying criteria you specify. Qualifying criteria could be an `if-then` type statement to check if numeric values fall in a certain range, or a regular expression (regex) to match string values. When the SearchCursor finishes, if you have only one field left in the fields list, you've identified the correct attribute.

```
#Untested example looking for a valid attribute of latitudes in California
#(could contain minor syntax errors)
potential_fields = arcpy.ListFields('table', field_type = 'Double')
with arcpy.SearchCursor('table') as rows:
    for row in rows:
        #Use a copy of the potential fields list
        for x in potential_fields[:]:
            v = row.getValue(x.name)
            #Eliminate the attribute from contention if it is outside the
            #bounds (here is where the qualifying criteria comes into play)
            if v < 32.5 or v >= 42.0:
                potential_fields.remove(x)
        #Quit trying if the potential fields list is empty
        if len(potential_fields) == 0:
            break

#Check the results
if len(potential_fields) == 0:
    #Code for if no attributes qualify
elif len(potential_fields) > 1:
    #Code for if multiple fields qualify
else:
    #Use potential_fields[0] as the latitude
```

There may be situations where this approach won't work, but it can work for many if the qualifying criteria is specific enough.

Comment: I'll have to give this a try, looks like it could definitely work for what I need it to do. But would this go in the library file or in the actual script its self?

Comment: If you have multiple instances where you would use the same qualifying criteria, make it into a function where the input parameter is the table and the return value is the potential fields list, and put it in the library. The if-elif-else section would go in the main program.

Comment: Is there any way to utilize this but using a CSV reader so I wouldn't have to bring Arc into the equation at all?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I've never tried it. You would have to keep track of the column index offsets for the columns that were still potential matches, and you may need to check the type of value (string, number, date, etc) the column contained before making a comparison with the qualifying criteria.